# Efficient way to query separate days of data?

Tags: sql, performance, pdo

I want to query statistics using SQL from 3 different days (in a row). The display would be something like:

> 15 users created today, 10 yesterday, 12 two days ago

The SQL would be something like (for today):

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM Users WHERE created_date >= '2012-05-11'
```

And then I would do 2 more queries for yesterday and the day before.

So in total I'm doing 3 queries against the entire database. The format for created_date is `2012-05-11 05:24:11` (date & time).

Is there a more efficient SQL way to do this, say in one query?

For specifics, I'm using PHP and SQLite (so the PDO extension).

The result should be 3 different numbers (one for each day).

Any chance someone could show some performance numbers in comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Count(*), created_date FROM Users GROUP BY created_date
```

That will give you a list of dates with the number of records found on that date. You can add criteria for `created_date` using a normal `WHERE` clause.

**Edit:** based on your edit:

```
SELECT Count(*), created_date FROM Users WHERE created_date>='2012-05-09' GROUP BY date(created_date)
```

Comment: Though correct, this query would return counts of users created since the beginning which, depending on the history, may be a very long result set.

Comment: I'm only looking for the last 3 days or so.

Comment: @EmmanuelG True, I was already adding a paragraph about that.

Comment: @JBurace That was kind of obvious that you could add a simple condition to get only last couple of days. Also, if coulmn is of DATETIME type you should use `DATE(created_date)` in `GROUP BY` so that it didn't group results by seconds.:)

Comment: `created_date` actually contains the day and time, so grouping wouldn't work since it would group by time as well. Suggestions?

Comment: @JBurace Take a look at @Slava's suggestion, `date` does exist in sqlite.

Comment: @JBurace Why do you need `if`? I have modified my second sql statement to show the change suggested by @Slava

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use `GROUP BY DAY(created_date)`. Here is your query:

```
SELECT DATE(created_date), count(*) 
FROM users
WHERE created_date > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY
GROUP BY DAY(created_date)
```

Comment: Yup, thats what I was homing in on.

Comment: I'm getting the error: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: DAY` on the "GROUP BY DAY"

Comment: I just tested it in MySQL and it works, perhaps there are some differences in MySQL and SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

This would work I believe though I have no way to test it:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT Count(*) FROM Users WHERE created_date >= '2012-05-11') as today,
  (SELECT Count(*) FROM Users WHERE created_date >= '2012-05-10') as yesterday,
  (SELECT Count(*) FROM Users WHERE created_date >= '2012-05-11') as day_before
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` like jeroen suggested, but if you're planning for other periods you can also set ranges like this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(created_date BETWEEN '2012-05-01' AND NOW(), 1, 0)) AS `this_month`,
       SUM(IF(created_date = '2012-05-09', 1, 0)) AS `2_days_ago`
FROM ...
```

As noted below, SQLite doesn't have `IF` function but there is `CASE` instead. So this way it should work:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN created_date BETWEEN '2012-05-01' AND NOW() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `this_month`,
       SUM(CASE created_date WHEN '2012-05-09' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `2_days_ago`
FROM ...
```

Comment: I am trying that but it's giving me `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: IF`

Comment: @JBurace Ah, sorry, I forgot about that. SQLite supports CASE instead.